A matching problem related to Hall's theorem
There are $m$ boys and $n$ girls, $m>n$. Each boy likes some girls, and they satisfy the perfect matching condition that for any group of boys, the number of girls that they like is equal to or greater than the number of boys in that group. So, by Hall's theorem, there is always a perfect matching.
If boy $B$ does not like any girl, then obviously he is not in the matching list. Is it possible that $B$ likes at least one girl, but definitely there is no $B$ in the matching list? That is, a matching list including $B$ does not exist.

If $n=1$, there is only one girl, and $B$ must like her. So, the list can possible have $B$, right?

If it satisfies the perfect matching condition then all boys are chosen, by definition + Hall's theorem

@CalvinLin My question is, is it possible that every matching list does not contain $B$? I cannot find an example and cannot prove it.

@BrunoAndrades No. There are more boys than girls. Some boys are not chosen.

Ah, I see what you want. $\quad$ Given any edge, there is a perfect matching that includes that edge (run through Hall Marriage on the reduced set), so the answer to your broader question is No. See here for the details - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501754/using-halls-theorem-to-show-graph-contains-a-perfect-matching-containing-any-edg

@CalvinLin Now I see a proof. For any boy $B$, if there is a group $S$ of boys containing $B$ such that $|N(S)|=|S|$, then $B$ must be in the matching list; otherwise, the matching condition is strict for every subset, by removing $B$ and its neighbors, there is still a perfect matching. Thank you!

If $m>n$ (more boys than girls) then your matching condition can only apply to groups with at most $n$ boys.   But it is possible to have a perfect matching without the matching condition being met for all such groups: for example have $m-n$ boys who do not like any girls and the matching condition met only when taking groups from the remaining $n$ boys

I’m confused. If $m>n$, this can’t satisfy Hall’s condition, since the set of all boys has fewer girls that they like. Do you mean to write it the other way, so for any set of girls, there’s more boys that like them than the number of girls? If B likes G, then can’t you just grab an arbitrary perfect matching and replace G’s dude with B?

@Eric I see what you mean. It should be the other way around, and the proof is simple.

@Henry You are correct. My argument that $|N(S)|=|S|$ implies $B$ must be in the list is wrong.
